# AngularJS search by file's name

Tags: json, angularjs, html

I have a bunch of .svg files with different names in my img folder and a json file. One of json's value is similar to the name of .svg files. How can I go through all image files and all "cca2" so I could compare their names with json's value and if they match display the one in img tag? I'm doing my project with AngularJS.

Example of json file:

```
[
    {
        "cca2": "AW"
    },
    {
        "cca2": "UA"
    },
    .....
]
```

Images: aw.svg, ua.svg etc.

"AW", "UA" and etc. are values which I want to be compared with names of image files

```
 for(var i = 0; i < $scope.totalItems; i++){
        if($scope.countries[i].currency + "" === "UAH"){
            console.log("Good");
        }
    }
```

"UAH" needs to be replaced with all names of .svg files

Structure of img folder:
http://s18.postimg.org/8xvtnmzop/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: Please show what you tried...you will need to iterate or filter the data array

Comment: @charlietfl I have no idea so why I am here, just stuck on this task

Comment: start by looping over the array and compare value of each one

Comment: @charlietfl Edited my question

Comment: Ok..question wasn't clear perhaps...you need to compare 2 arrays? If so need structure shown for both. I thought you were looking just for one at a time

Comment: @charlietfl Check the link above

Comment: @charlietfl If one of all elements in the countries array is similar to the name of one of all image files then I want to display that picture

Comment: In other words you have array from image folder, and need to see if you have a match for each country? Higher level objective is still fuzzy

Comment: @charlietfl For an instance, I want to display Ukraine, so "ukr.svg" will be the right image. I can bind file name of image - "ukr" with "cca3" value from json which is "ukr" too and then I can display it. I can loop through an "cca3" but how I can loop through bunch of images to get the name of each one

Comment: @charlietfl Now you've got the idea?

Comment: create a sample of files array data

Comment: @charlietfl can you give me an example of code whcih is doing this , cause I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @charlietfl can you help me with this?

Comment: yes but create some sample data to work with. Will need to loop over all the countries, then look in the files array to see if there is a match

Comment: @charlietfl I don't understand what do you mean by "files array", cause there is just a folder with files and I need to loop through the name of each file.

Comment: that has to be done at server... javascript in browser can't read that directory

Comment: @charlietfl What about FileReader?